# Migrate binary data from PostgreSQL database into Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, database-migration

I have PostgreSQL database in version 9.1 with table that contains column named BinContent configured as **BYTEA** data type. My target is to migrate/convert this table to Microsoft SQL Server (2008) column configured as **IMAGE** data type.

When I'm trying to do that conversion i got following error:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "POSTGRES2" returned message "Requested   conversion is not supported.". 
Msg 7341, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the current row value of column "[MSDASQL].bincontent" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "POSTGRES2".
```

Comment: Are you the same person who asked importing a CSV containing an image from MS-SQL into PostgreSQL?

Comment: Nope. I don't know that post.

Comment: Huh, it must just be import-from-mssql-day. Funny. Can't really help you on this one, as the error seems to be on the MS-SQL side and I haven't used it much at all.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this question? I have  a similar requirement.